# What version of Google Chrome do I have?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, versions

How can I find out what version of chrome I am using?

I would like a command line method, not the GUI - visiting `chrome://chrome` in the url bar. I need to be able to use it in a bash script.

I ran the command `google-chrome --help`, but it didn't seem to have a `--version` option.

Comment: How did you look for the `version` option in the help? Scrolling through? Does it not list the option if you do `google-chrome --help | grep version`?

Comment: Probably, but most basic users won't which is why I asked and answered the question :) I missed it myself first time.

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice this was a self answered question =D. My bad.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It does have the option listed:

```
OPTIONS
       Google  Chrome has hundreds of undocumented command-line flags that are
       added and removed at the whim of the  developers.   Here,  we  document
       relatively stable flags.  

       ...

       --version
              Show version information.
```

So you can use the command `google-chrome` with the `--version` option:

```
google-chrome --version
```

gives:

```
    Google Chrome 36.0.1985.125
```

For the following commands, I am using `grep` and regex, because it is much more adaptable to changes in Google Chrome version format changes

To get just the version number run the following command:

```
google-chrome --version | grep -iE "[0-9.]{10,20}"
```

It gives:

```
    36.0.1985.125
```

And this one:

```
google-chrome --version | grep -iE " [0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}
```

gives you just the main version numbers.

```
    36.0
```

If you have beta installed:

Running this command:

```
google-chrome-beta --version
```

gives:

```
Google Chrome 37.0.2062.58 beta
```

And then there are the gui methods:

You can go to the following sites:

```
chrome://chrome
```

gives you this:

[image]

And

```
chrome://version
```

or

```
about:
```

<sup>Thanks [Jeff Inventor Chrome OS](https://askubuntu.com/a/505726/186134).</sup>

gives this:

[image]

```
Google Chrome   36.0.1985.125 (Official Build 283153) 
OS  Linux 
Blink   537.36 (@177902)
JavaScript  V8 3.26.31.8
Flash   14.0.0.145
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
Profile Path    /home/tim/.config/google-chrome/Default
Variations  e950616e-37fb3cc2
            c70841c8-4866ef6e
            3664a344-be9e69ba
            9e5c75f1-ad69ceb0
            24dca50e-837c4893
            ca65a9fe-91ac3782
            8d790604-9cb2a91c
            4ea303a6-3d47f4f4
            d8f57532-f23d1dea
            b2612322-f8cf70e2
            5a3c10b5-e1cc0f14
            244ca1ac-4ad60575
            5e29d81-f23d1dea
            3ac60855-486e2a9c
            246fb659-bca011b3
            f296190c-cdc3d902
            4442aae2-4ad60575
            ed1d377-e1cc0f14
            75f0f0a0-4ad60575
            e2b18481-a5822863
            e7e71889-e1cc0f14
            cbf0c14e-bf3e6cfd
```

My pronouns are He / Him

Answer (score 12):

Below command will give the version details only:

```
google-chrome --product-version
```

Output:

```
78.0.3904.70
```

Comment: ```IFS='.' read major minor build patch < <(google-chrome --product-version); echo "${major}.${minor}"```

Answer (score 4):

For a more generic solution you can use `apt-cache policy`, e.g.:

```
$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: 36.0.1985.125-1
  Candidate: 36.0.1985.125-1
```

This will work with all software installed through your package manager.

Comment: That gives `36.0.1985.125-1 0` what is the `-1 0` at the end?

Comment: @Tim That's the "debian revision". See [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/deb-version.5.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $(google-chrome --version | awk '{print $3}')
```

output:

```
78.0.3904.97
```

Answer (score 2):

**about:** also works.  It gives the full version info of the browser, Blink, Javascript, and Flash.

Comment: Yeah, that redirects to `chrome://version/`

Comment: Have added into the main answer and linked yours for kudos.