# What are all of the command line options for Google Chrome?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I use Google Chrome as my main browser, and I wanted to know what things I can do with it from command line - especially commands that you can't do with the GUI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Chrome has these stable options. There are other non stable ones, but they can be added and removed whenever the developers want, so I haven't included them, to keep this up to date.

I have written the option, then example, then explanation.

---

```
--user-data-dir=DIR

google-chrome --user-data-dir=/home/tim/chromedatadir
```

This is used to tell google chrome where to save your data (bookmarks, history, anything peronalised to you). This is the way to create a new session - just running `google-chrome` simply opens a new tab. Use a directory you have just created. The default is `~/.config/google-chrome`.

---

```
--app=URL

google-chrome --app=http://google.co.uk
```

This creates a new window with no tool bars - e.g. No bookmarks bar, or tab bar or omnibar. See the screenshot below (that is Google, I just have a custom background <sup>1</sup>).

[image]

---

```
--incognito

google-chrome --incognito
```

Opens an incognito window.

> Pages that you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store or search history after you've closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files that you download or bookmarks that you create will be kept.

As you can see (top right) all my extensions (except ad block, because I have enabled that) are disabled in incognito.

[image]

---

```
--proxy-server=host:port

google-chrome --proxy-server="socks5://foobar:66"
```

This specifies the HTTP/SOCKS4/SOCKS5 proxy server to use for requests. It overrides any environment variables or settings picked  via the  options  dialog, via the GUI settings.   An  individual proxy server is specified using the format:

```
[<proxy-scheme>://]<proxy-host>[:<proxy-port>]
```

`<proxy-scheme>` is the protocol of the proxy server, and is one of the following 4:

```
"http", "socks", "socks4", "socks5"
```

---

```
--no-proxy-server

google-chrome --no-proxy-server
```

Disables  the proxy server.  Overrides any environment variables or settings picked via the GUI settings.

---

```
--proxy-auto-detect

google-chrome --proxy-auto-detect
```

Autodetect proxy configuration.  Overrides any environment variables or settings picked via the GUI settings.

---

```
--proxy-pac-url=URL

google-chrome --proxy-pac-url=URL
```

Specify  proxy auto configuration URL.  Overrides any environment variables or settings picked via the GUI settings.

---

```
--password-store=<basic|gnome|kwallet>

google-chrome --password-store=gnome
```

Set the password store to use.  The default is to  automatically detect  based  on  the  desktop  environment.  `basic` selects the built in,  unencrypted  password  store.   `gnome`  selects  Gnome keyring.  `kwallet` selects (KDE) `KWallet`.  (Note that `KWallet` may not work reliably outside KDE.)

---

```
--version

google-chrome --version
```

(return `Google Chrome 36.0.1985.143`)

Shows version information.

Perhaps more useful is

```
echo 'google-chrome --version' | sed -nre "s/.* ([0-9.]+)/\1/p"
```

(return `36.0.1985.143`)

As that returns just the version number, without `Google Chrome` at the beginning.

There is more information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505531/what-version-of-google-chrome-do-i-have) about ways of manipulating the `--version` option.

---

<sup>1 [Custom Google™ Background](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jepibmfmhopgkplegmkjgifmhabbjadg)</sup>

Comment: A single, but essential \` tick is missing at basic1

Comment: --version: `$ echo 'Google Chrome 36.0.1985.143' | sed -nre "s/.* ([0-9.]+)/\1/p"` - grep is probably not what you _meant_ here. :-)

Comment: Yes, that is where. grep displays the line that matches, but you have `(return 36.0.1985.143)` which is not the full line - rather it looks as the output from sed ^-- as I wrote.

Comment: Ahh... Sorry to confuse you. Note that I do not have Chrome installed so I used 'echo' to _simulate_ the output - that is `echo 'Google Chrome 36.0.1985.143'` equals producing the same output as `google-chrome --version` - sorry! ;-)

Comment: @Tim Can you advise where to go to see ALL the options offered by chrome? Not just the ones on the man page?

Comment: @SeekTruth I expect you’d probably have to look at the code. They change quite regularly: I don’t even know if the list in my answer is up to date.

Comment: Thank you. I finally found it and posted in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to see these options on the man page:

```
man google-chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for options not shown in the man page?

Here is an essential one to **increase the size of everything in chrome.**

```
--force-device-scale-factor=
```

Number to scale is attached to the equals sign with no spaces. Typically somewhere between `1.0`-`2.0`

Example:

```
google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1.25
```

The following link contains an extensive list switches/options available for chrome [thank you Peter](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)